# Junit test (using when and Mockito verifyNoMoreInteractions)

Tags: java, testing, junit

I am doing Junit test on controller methods. One of the methods has two dependencies (calling two different methods from my service) Thus I've used "*when*" twice in my @test function.

@controller

```
@Autowired
private CustomerAccountService customerAccountService;
@GetMapping("/customer/accountStatement")
public String accountStatement(Model model, HttpSession session) {
    
    LoginVO loginVO2 = (LoginVO) session.getAttribute("userSessionVO");
    
    if(loginVO2 != null) {
        Optional <CustomerAccountInfoVO> check = customerAccountService.customerInfo(loginVO2.getUsername());
        List <AccountStatementVO> newData = customerAccountService.accountStatement(check.get().getAccountNumber());
        model.addAttribute("accState", newData);
        return "customer/accountStatement";
    }else {
        return "customer/login";
    }
```

@Junit (test passes like this)

```
@Mock
private CustomerAccountService customerAccountService;

@InjectMocks
private CustomerUIController customerUIController;

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Before
public void init() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(customerUIController).build();
    
}
@Test
public void testAccountStatement() throws Exception {
    
    HashMap<String, Object> session = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    LoginVO loginVO2 = new LoginVO();
    loginVO2.setUsername("Joe");
    loginVO2.setEmail("Joe@hotmail.com");
    session.put("userSessionVO", loginVO2);
    
    CustomerAccountInfoVO customerAccountInfoVO = new CustomerAccountInfoVO();
    customerAccountInfoVO.setAccountNumber("221");
    customerAccountInfoVO.setAccountType("Saving");
    customerAccountInfoVO.setAvBalance(123);
    customerAccountInfoVO.setCustomerId("Joe@hotmail.com");
    customerAccountInfoVO.setCurrency("Dollar");

    AccountStatementVO accountStatementVO = new AccountStatementVO();
    accountStatementVO.setAmount(3234);
    accountStatementVO.setCreditorAccountNumber("22331");
    accountStatementVO.setRemarks("hello");
    accountStatementVO.setDebitorAccountNumber("2211");
    List<AccountStatementVO> listdata = new ArrayList<AccountStatementVO>();
    listdata.add(accountStatementVO);
    
    when(customerAccountService.customerInfo(any(String.class))).thenReturn(Optional.of(customerAccountInfoVO));
    when(customerAccountService.accountStatement(any(String.class))).thenReturn(listdata);
    
    mockMvc.perform(get("/customer/accountStatement").sessionAttrs(session))
                            .andDo(print())
                            .andExpect(status().isOk())
                            .andExpect(view().name("customer/accountStatement"))
                            .andExpect(model().attribute("accState", hasItem(
                                    allOf(
                                            hasProperty("remarks", is("hello")),
                                            hasProperty("debitorAccountNumber", is("2211"))
                                    )
                                    )));
                            
    verify(customerAccountService, times(1)).customerInfo(any(String.class));
    verify(customerAccountService, times(1)).accountStatement(any(String.class));
    verifyNoMoreInteractions(customerAccountService);
```

Error -
when I run my method like this, I get error (test fails) 
 It says - *org.mockito.exceptions.verification.NoInteractionsWanted:  No interactions wanted here:*

```
verify(customerAccountService, times(1)).customerInfo(any(String.class));
verifyNoMoreInteractions(customerAccountService);
```

Passes test -

```
verify(customerAccountService, times(1)).customerInfo(any(String.class));
verify(customerAccountService, times(1)).accountStatement(any(String.class));
verifyNoMoreInteractions(customerAccountService);
```

Question - 
Do we have to call *verify* as many times as *when* ? 
what is other ways to perform Junit test when we have more than one dependencies in our controller?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no need of a match between verify and when.
Just don't call `verifyNoMoreInteractions` if you are not interested in verifying every interaction. If you call it, you tell mockito, that everything you did not verify explicitly is unexpected behaviour and therfore should fail the test.